# Delphi dynamic form array and data array management

Tags: forms, delphi, dynamic

I have to solve next problem:

Form23:

```
public
 { Public declarations }
 FormsArray : array of TForm24;
end;


Procedure Create_form;
begin
 SetLength(FormsArray, Length(FormsArray)+1);
 FormsArray[Length(FormsArray)-1] := TForm24.Create(Self);
end;
```

Form24:

```
public
end;

var
 UniqueValue : Array of ShortString;

Procedure Fill_Unique;
var
 tmp1 : Longint;
begin
 SetLength(UniqueValue, 256);
 for tmp1 := 0 to Length(UniqueValue)-1 do
 begin
  UniqueValue[tmp1] := IntToStr(tmp1);
 end;
end;

Procedure OnButtonClick(Sender);
begin
 Fill_Unique;
end;
```

When i have one form Form24 and i fill with some values, then it is ok.

When i have two forms Form24 (FormsArray[0] and FormsArray[1]) and i change UniqueValue in one form, then i have that values in two forms.

i.e.

I create FormsArray[0] and FormsArray[1]

When I click button on FormsArray[0]:

FormsArray[0] - UniqueValue[...] = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...';

FormsArray[1] - UniqueValue[...] = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...';

When I click button on FormsArray[1]:

FormsArray[0] - UniqueValue[...] = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...';

FormsArray[1] - UniqueValue[...] = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...';

When i change code to:

Form24:

```
public
 UniqueValue : Array of ShortString;
end;
```

and I click button on FormsArray[1] then i have:

FormsArray[0] - UniqueValue[...] = '';

FormsArray[1] - UniqueValue[...] = '';

UniqueValue is empty.

I need to have independent arrays in every forms Form24 i have created (different UniqueValue in every forms i create).

How to do this? What i do wrong?

Thanks for any help.

**SOLVED !**

I got -1 for solution what i write here. Then will be no solution. Search for yourself.

Comment: Everything you stated in your "solution" is either irrelevant (you never showed us what you call, so who cares where you call it from or when?) or repeating what you already stated in the question (the array of forms). Didn't you mean to show the new declaration of the array of *strings*, like I already showed in my answer?

Comment: Problem isn't in code, but from calling method. I did not know where error is. If I knew, I would not ask. I post solution, where is main problem with this situation (if someone got this problem, because is very difficult to locate). I got a -1, then i will delete solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've already solved it. Make `UniqueValue` be a *member of the form class*. Put it in the `public` section of the class declaration, for example.

```
type
  TForm24 = class(TForm)
  public
    UniqueValue: array of string;
  end;
```

The first code you showed has the array as a *global variable*, which is of course shared by all instances of your form class, as well as everything else in your program. You're probably confused thinking that anything declared in the same file as the form class somehow "belongs to" that class, but if you think that, you're mistaken. To make something belong to a class, it should be declared *inside* that class, not just somewhere in the same unit file.

It looks like you'll probably want to make `Fill_Unique` and `OnButtonClick` be members of the form class, too. In the code you showed, they're standalone procedures, so they have no reference to whatever form they're supposed to work on. That means they can't refer to `UniqueValue` because they won't know which `TForm24` instance's field to operate on.

Comment: So i need to move Fill_Unique to Form23 and fill array UniqueValue from Form23? it is only solution?

Comment: I meant that you would move `Fill_Unique` to `TForm24` since it's fields of `TForm24` that it operates on. You could also keep `Fill_Unique` as a standalone function, but then give it a parameter of type `TForm24`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UniqueValue` array is declared globally, so multiple form instances are going to access the same array in memory.  Moving the array into the `public` section of your Form class allows each instance of that Form to have its own array that is independant of other Form instances.  Just make sure you remove the global array.

Comment: When i do this i have as a result empty array (FormsArray[1] = '')

Comment: What you claim doesn't make sense, Wcale. FormsArray is an array of *forms*, so no element of it would be equal to an empty string.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake "UniqueValue is empty." not FormsArray. I have solution as You said when i used a button (I'am edit question). Thanks for help.

Comment: Thn please show your updated code.  If the array is empty, then you are obviously not filling it in correctly.

Comment: I'am updated my post. Procedure OnButtonClick(Sender); has been called from popupMenu - that has cause problem. When i called it from TButton - this error never show again. UniqueValue in every FormArrays are different, filled correctly and accessible from Form24.